# Using Intermediate value theorem and Rolle's theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification

> Find how many solutions $2\ln x+2x^2+7=0$ has.

Define: $f(x)=2\ln x+2x^2+7$, derive it and equate to $0$:

$f'(x)=0 \\ 2+4x^2=0$

The discriminant is negative so there are no solutions, so from Rolle we know that $f$ has at most one solution.

Place values in $f$ for IVT:

$f(0.01)=2\cdot(-4.6)+0+7<0 \\ f(1)=0+2+7 >0 $

So from IVT we know that there's a solution between $0.01$ and $1$.

Is my use of the two theorems correct?

Comment: Yes, they are. (Though, $\ln(0.01)\color{maroon}{\approx} -4.6$.)

Comment: But in your approximate evaluation of $f(0.01)$, you should not write $f(0.01) = 2\cdot (-4.6) + 0 + 7$, since that's not true, it's $f(0.01) \approx \dotsc$.

Comment: Ah alright David and Daniel. Thank you.